# JavaScript event.target only reports child (MooTools)

Tags: javascript, events, dom-events, mootools

I seem to get something fundamentally wrong. I have this HTML

```html
<div id="thumbnails">
    <a href="#image-0">
        <img src="blabla-1.jpg" />
    </a>
    <a href="#image-0">
        <img src="blabla-1.jpg" />
    </a>
    <a href="#image-0">
        <img src="blabla-1.jpg" />
    </a>
</div>
```

and this JavaScript (MooTools library in use)

```js
document.id('thumbnails').getElements('a').each(function(image_link, image_link_index)
{
    image_link.addEvent('click', function(evt)
    {
        if (evt.target.get('tag') == 'a')
        {
            evt.stop();
            console.log('a tag', evt.target);
        }

        console.log(':-(', evt.target);
    });
});
```

Strangely I never get to that a element. I'm sure I'm misunderstanding something basic here.

You can play around with the code at http://jsfiddle.net/maryisdead/kHBE3/8/

Comment: Are the ID's and sources all supposed to be the same?

Comment: No … too late here, sorry. It's all part of a gallery (thumbnails and big images) and the images and anchors are actually different. Doesn't relate to the problem though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

why are you reinventing the wheel? event delegation is not something to be taken lightly - and you should use the built-in event-delegation (since 1.4.1) http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element.Delegation

your code would change to:

```
document.id('thumbnails').addEvent('click:relay(a)', function(evt, el) {
    evt.stop();
    console.log(':-)', el.get("tag") == 'a', this.get("tag") == 'a');
});
```

where the `relay()` pseudo can take any selector you like - eg. a.foo or a[href=#]

keep in mind that in 1.2 the event delegation was sort of experimental and somewhat less than perfect - when it came to `mouseover:relay()` or `focus:relay(input[type=text])` you can get some unexpected results in different browsers - issues addressed in 1.3.2 iirc. Also, `change` events on checkboxes and radios in old ie6/7/8 revert to onpropertychange and may not bubble.

in any case, yours fails to come through to the anchor link as the `event.target` as the event itself BUBBLES from the top down. i.e. it will start from `img > a > thumbnails` but it won't raise different events for both - it will be the same `event.target` on both all 3 elements yet -> this === a

what you can do though is `console.log(this.get("tag") === 'a')); // true` - even though the initial target was the child of `this`

Comment: Clarified, thank you. I always thought the event would go up and down again as per http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html and that the target would change depending on where the event "is".

Your code example solves my problem as well. Didn't know about this one.

Thank you, perfect answer!

Comment: come to think of it, you are correct. its different events, same event structure (event.target is the constant). updated.

Answer (score 1):

<del>If you're going to use `event` inside your code, you need to have the argument named `event`, not `evt`. Fix that, and you should be good to go.</del>

I have no idea why it doesn't work. The event is firing on the image inside the link, not the link itself which is just flat out weird.

The only thing I can suggest (it doesn't fix it) is an easier way to select the elements.

```
$$('#thumbnails > a').each(...
```

I also just tried rewriting the same code to use my own toolkit, which is jQuery like. It still has the same problem, which means it's something JavaScript specific, not MooTools specific.

You could try `if (evt.target.parentNode.get('tag') == 'a')`

Comment: Hey, thanks for your efforts. I can't get my head around it, no idea why I never experienced that before. I now went your route, looking for a parent element jsfiddle.net/maryisdead/kHBE3/23